# Grep-ing classes / functions from projects

Tags: python, search, vim, tags, grep

Is there a way in grep (or vim) to print out a named function/class?

i.e. From:

```
    class InternalTimer(Sim.Process):
        def __init__(self, fsm):
            Sim.Process.__init__(self, name="Timer")
            random.seed()
            self.fsm = fsm

        def Lifecycle(self, Request):
            while True:
                yield Sim.waitevent, self, Request
                yield Sim.hold, self, Request.signalparam[0]
                if(self.interrupted()):
                    self.interruptReset()
                else:
                self.fsm.process(Request.signalparam[1])
```

Calling `$my-func-grep '__init__(self,fsm)' filename.py` would produce

```
        def __init__(self, fsm):
            Sim.Process.__init__(self, name="Timer")
            random.seed()
            self.fsm = fsm
```

Comment: Calling **$fgrep '__init__(self,fsm)' filename.py** should produce only **def __init__(self, fsm):**. You want the function definition?

Comment: If you have a `tags` file, you can do `:pt __init__` to see the function's signature.

Comment: @tuxuday no, I want to print out the function, in this case I was using fgrep as a joking imaginary function-grepper. Didn't think that fgrep has been overloaded on to classical grep. Updated example to be clearer

Answer (score 3):

You could create a vim extension which effectively performs the following:

```
import inspect
print inspect.getsource(name_of_function)
```

This prints the function signature and the body of the function. If Vim has been compiled with Python support, you can write extensions in Python itself.